Not able to use service name as URL for communication between services in k8 cluster
I have a k8 cluster where API A (k8 service manifest exist) needs to be able to talk to API B (no k8 service manifest exists since I want it internal). Using the Docker Compose we can specify the API by name in the URL ie.
If the name of the service in the Docker Compose is api-b then we can use
http://api-b:8080/

I have done some research and it seems we have to use a different format for k8 and that's the following
http://api-b.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/

api-b is what is defined in the deployment manifest as the "name"
This approach doesn't seem to work and I get an error like

Name or service not known (api-b.default.svc.cluster.local:8080)

I am aware when the cluster is deployed, the name of the Pod is api-b-6f699f6fd9 (as hash appended to the end). Does this impact it? Is it because there is no service manifest for api-b (only deployment one)? If not, anyone got an idea of something I can try?
Note: I used Kompose to auto generate the k8 manifests from a Docker Compose file

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The short name api-b should still work so long as the calling Pod and the destination Service are in the same namespace.  From what I've seen in other SO questions, it seems to be common to need to edit the Kompose output to make it work properly.

The main issue you’re facing is that API B doesn’t have a Kubernetes Service manifest. In Kubernetes, the service discovery works through DNS, but it relies on having a Service resource. A Service provides a stable DNS entry and load balances to the underlying Pods.
The Pod name (e.g., api-b-6f699f6fd9) changes with each deployment, which makes it unreliable for direct communication. The stable way to refer to a set of Pods is through a Service.
The DNS name api-b.default.svc.cluster.local works if there is a Service named api-b in the default namespace.
I’ll suggest you follow these steps to resolve the issue :

Create a Service for API B:
Even if you want API B to be internal, you should create a ClusterIP Service for it. This will make sure that API A can resolve api-b to the correct Pods.
Here’s an example of a minimal Service manifest for API B:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-b
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: api-b
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080


Check Labels on API B Pods:
Make sure the Pods created by the Deployment for API B have a label that matches the selector in the Service. Typically, this is handled automatically if you used Kompose, but it’s good to verify.
Example Deployment manifest for API B:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-b
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-b
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-b
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-b
        image: your-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080



Verifying the Setup

Deploy the Service:
Apply the Service manifest:
kubectl apply -f api-b-service.yaml


Check DNS Resolution:
Once the Service is deployed, check if the DNS entry resolves correctly from within the cluster. You can exec into any Pod in the same namespace and use nslookup or curl:
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/sh
nslookup api-b.default.svc.cluster.local
curl http://api-b.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/



Or simply try accessing API B from API A as you did before.
API A should now be able to communicate with API B using the internal DNS name provided by Kubernetes, and it will work consistently even if the Pods are redeployed or scaled.
Hope this helps.

Amazing response thank you, I had a feeling it was that I needed to define a service manifest for api-b (ive had to change a number of things after the Kompose generation already). I will try this shortly and accept if it works. Appreciate your time and this seems like it will be the answer!

You are welcome.  Glad you found it helpful and clear.
